# how to use webkit-text-size-adjust in safari javascript console

Tags: javascript, safari, webkit, mobile-safari

I am trying to debug a javascript function with different font sizes. After the document has been loaded, in Safari's javascript console I execute:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.webkitTextSizeAdjust="120\%"
```

To no effect at all.

This code increases the text size to 120% in mobile safari. Can it be that it is limited to there? Any other ideas, why it doesn't work in desktop safari?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like its only available iOS 1.0 and later.

[Safari CSS Reference -webkit-text-size-adjust](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariCSSRef/Articles/StandardCSSProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001266--webkit-text-size-adjust)